# :after doesn't scope by relative of parent

Tags: css

I have :after for my animation, as you can see it isn't scoped by the relative. What I want is the bar should start from the width of the bar itself, now it's from the far left. What's the issue here?

```
.loading {
    position: relative;
  background-color: #E2E2E2;

  &::after {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent, rgba(255, 255, 255, .4), transparent);
    animation: loading 1s infinite;
  }
}
```

https://media.giphy.com/media/Vek3fMxjoA4qxGveZr/giphy.gif

try to inspect the :after DOM in this demo
https://codepen.io/eldyvoon/pen/vMVgaO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do not use `transform: translateX(-100%)`, it will start from outside left of your `.loading`, and add `left: 0`

```
.loading { 
  position: relative;
  background-color: #E2E2E2;
  overflow: hidden;
  &::after {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    /* transform: translateX(-100%); */
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent, rgba(100, 255, 255, .4), transparent);
    animation: loading 1s infinite;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `overflow:hidden` to `.loading`

furthermore, you can see it works well with changing `::after`' `background-color`

```
.loading {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #E2E2E2;
  overflow: hidden;
  &::after {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent, rgba(100, 255, 255, .4), transparent);
    animation: loading 1s infinite;
  }
}
```

Comment: it still not starting from the bar itself.

Comment: @Hanz because you are using `transform: translatex()`.

Comment: so what is the solution?